# Null Pointer Exception in logcat

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

am facing the null pointer Exception.In Xml i add two images and drawView in the layout.By clicking the Image  i want to draw that color on the surface but its not working .
Refer this code and solve the error plz.

```
**MainActivity:**

        public class `MainActivity` extends Activity {



             private Paint mPaint;  
               View content;
             @Override  
             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

              /*layout.addView(mView, new LayoutParams(  
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); */ 
              init(); 
              ImageView next = ( ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
              next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(View view) {
                       mPaint = new Paint();  
                       mPaint.setDither(true);  

                       mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);  
                       mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);  
                       mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);  
                       mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
                      mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);  
                   }
               });

              DrawView  drawingSurface = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.drawingSurface);

              content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

             }  

             private void init() {  
              mPaint = new Paint();  
              mPaint.setDither(true);  
              mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF00);  
              mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);  
              mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);  
              mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);  
              mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);  
             }  
        }



**DrawView.java**


    public class DrawView extends View {  
          private Path path;  
          private Bitmap mBitmap;  
          private Canvas mCanvas;  
          private Paint mPaint; 

          public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {  
           super(context,attrs);  
           path = new Path();  
           mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(820, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
           mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);  
           this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);  
          }  

          private ArrayList<PathWithPaint> _graphics1 = new ArrayList<PathWithPaint>();  

          @Override  
          public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {  
           PathWithPaint pp = new PathWithPaint();  
           mCanvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);  
           if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {  
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());  
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());  
           } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {  
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());  
            pp.setPath(path);  
            pp.setmPaint(mPaint);  
            _graphics1.add(pp);  
           }  
           invalidate();  
           return true;  
          }  

          @Override  
          protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {  
           super.onDraw(canvas);  
           if (_graphics1.size() > 0) {  
            canvas.drawPath(  
              _graphics1.get(_graphics1.size() - 1).getPath(),  
              _graphics1.get(_graphics1.size() - 1).getmPaint());  
           }  
          }  
         }  

**pathwithpaint.java**


    public class PathWithPaint {


        private Path path;  

         public Path getPath() {  
          return path;  
         }  

         public void setPath(Path path) {  
          this.path = path;  
         }  

         private Paint mPaint;  

         public Paint getmPaint() {  
          return mPaint;  
         }  

         public void setmPaint(Paint mPaint) {  
          this.mPaint = mPaint;  
         }  

    }


Logcat 

    Errors

    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ex/com.example.ex.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at com.example.ex.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    03-19 19:08:36.997: E/AndroidRuntime(478):  ... 11 more


Xml File


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:id="@+id/myDrawing"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <com.example.ex.DrawView 
          android:id="@+id/drawingSurface"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="67dp" 
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please add the logcat

Comment: and show the line where it happens. Oh and when you know the line, you might be able to fix it by yourself by checking which used variable might be null...

Comment: Please provide your xml file where & how you used DrawView in xml file. I think the problem is with your droidview in xml file.

Answer (score 1):

View `content` in activity is not initialized. so when you try to access

```
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

it will be null.

Comment: How to initializ the content can u help me